# Authenticate connected app with Salesforce Integration User

Tags: integration, connected-apps, userlicense

We are installing a package that has an integration to an external system. The external system requires authentication with a connected app.

We don't want to tie the authentication/integration to a single user's login credentials in the event that the user's record is deactivated.

We want to use the "[Salesforce Integration User](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_integration_license.htm&release=242&type=5)" license that comes free with salesforce. However, we can't successfully login through the connected app because the user is API only and we get an error.

How can we use the Salesforce Integration User with an external connected app?

Comment: I believe the SFDC Integration User is intended for inbound API transactions. Integration with the external system (outbound API) is done using the external system's credentials. Perhaps I'm not fully understanding the flow of control here in your question.

Comment: @cropredy This is for a coveo integration. We need to login with a connected app provided by them, and we would like to use the SFDC Integration User

https://docs.coveo.com/en/1153/coveo-for-salesforce/configuring-the-coveo-for-salesforce-application

Comment: ah -- the app is a SFDC appexchange app; I ran into this same issue on a different use case -- the only way I worked around this was to use a different, full-featured Salesforce license "service account-type" user.

Comment: That's unfortunate, this is a great use case for an integration user. Thank you for commenting though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you gave ([Coveo's Salesforce app](https://docs.coveo.com/en/1153/coveo-for-salesforce/configuring-the-coveo-for-salesforce-application)), you can see it wants access to UX-y things in your SFDC (e.g. `access to Lightning applications`).

Since the SFDC Integration User license is API only (and can't be used for any UX work, this OAuth access isn't going to work.

[image]

### Workaround

Use a separate normal Salesforce license "service account" user for this integration.. If Coveo is updating your org, then dedicating a license (`coveo-integration@mycompany.com`) will give you traceability for updates it performs (what you were probably trying to do with the Salesforce API user)

Answer (score 0):

just to complete cropredy answer, Coveo indeed recommend to have dedicated Salesforce Crawling User.

You can find more details about the requirements of this user in Coveo's documentation: https://docs.coveo.com/en/1052/coveo-for-salesforce/configuring-a-salesforce-source#creating-a-dedicated-salesforce-crawling-user

Comment: This should be a comment under cropredy's answer. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.